# How do you clip an image from the bottom left in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am reading in a bitmap that is quite large and has a lot of useless space. The original image height is 2048 and the width is 1024.

I want to crop/clip the image for display purposes starting from the bottom left and showing an image height of 1047 and width of 1024 in c#. I've tried using CroppedBitmap but I keep getting an out of bounds error.

(The code below shows some random parameters as I started inputting a lot of stuff to get it to work even a little.)

This gives me the error:

```
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap((BitmapSource)bitmapImage,
                                     new Int32Rect(2048,0,30,50));
```

**EDIT:** To put it another way, I want to get rid of the top half of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(
                           bitmapImage,
                           new Int32Rect(0, (int)(bitmapImage.Height/2),
                           (int)bitmapImage.Width, (int)(bitmapImage.Height/2));
```

This will create a CroppedBitmap from the lower half of the bitmapImage. The Int32Rect should describe the part you want to keep.